# Error 403 when using the Google+ API

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

In short, I am trying to create an Android application which authenticates the user through the Google + API, and then sends the access token to a server, which in turn should use it to get information about the user. The issue is that I am getting a 403 error when accessing the Google + API from the server.

The URL used: `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29.1.AADtN_WKfJMEKntMj4_Trggaf-ngs7CTkfwuBXAprdFGpvXQi2Ea7tCfwrasUPLe0w-y6AuODp-MyXEyYvcTPZU-8FZbNrSD3UXYQBfmLun7dIon0txvCukESf6EUg1vVSi5_88ysAn1`

The message received:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I have also tried to send the access token through the `Authorization` header, but I get the same response.

I have enabled every Google+ API I can find, but I am still getting this error:

[image]

And this is how I am getting the acces token from the client Android application:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(SignInActivity.this, plusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:" + PLUS_PROFILE + " " + PLUS_LOGIN)
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? I am not trying to create a super secure application, as it's just for a school project, but I still need to access user information from the server.

Comment: Did you tried uninstalling the app and then running it again?

Comment: I just tried it, and strangely, the API gave me the same access token. I suppose I have to wait until the current one expires.